# Why is it so difficult to find the printer status in windows?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, printing

Using C# - I'm trying to find a list of all printers that are local and online (i.e. connected and ready to accept print requests)

I know the printer driver works - jobs will just wait until the printer is back online, but I need to find those specific that are online. These are clearly available to windows but the .net framework doesn't seem to accurately expose those which are currently online.

I'm trying to use lots of different methods and none seem to accurately work

```
// Get a list of available printers.
var printServer = new PrintServer();
var printQueues = printServer.GetPrintQueues(new[] { EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Local, EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Connections });
foreach (PrintQueue printQueue in printQueues)
{
    Console.WriteLine(printQueue.IsOffline); // This works for IsOffline, but doesn't tell us those that are online - and it's not an inverse relationship  
}
```

very frustrating - any help appreciated.

Should add I'm using windows 8.1, and the solution should work also with win 7+

Edit:

So given the following collection of printers :

[image: List of Printers - some offline]

I would expect to see something along the lines of

```
Getting all Printers
Send To OneNote 2013 : Online
Pack1 : Offine
Microsoft XPS Document Writer : Online
Fax : Online
EPSONB12B28 (XP-412 413 415 Series) : Offine
Brother MFC-9970CDW Printer : Online
```

But they are ALWAYS reported as Online on any status I see

Comment: What, exactly, is your question? You want to know why it's difficult? Or would you be satisfied with a method that works?

Comment: Well - mostly I want a method where the printer online status is matched with what the API call tells me. All the methods are great at giving me the names and supported paper sizes - not one reliably gives me whether the printer is currently online or not

Comment: This is why most print manufacturers have sophisticated drivers with bi-di communications.  They handle that in a propitiatory way.  You could try SNMP to pull more data but would need to know about the printer in more detail (ie: port etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I have queried just about every conceivable windows device either by native driver or using Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) classes.

To get you started, take a read of this article with C# source: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/80680/Managing-Printers-Programatically-using-C-and-WMI

Also, not in C# but VB, some quick glance info on the same subject here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394598(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394598%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Full WMI reference here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394572(v=VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394572%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Cheers and good luck!

Comment: Thanks for these - I've looked thorough these very same articles, and whilst they seem to have the info I need, I can't get access to the Availability attribute of the printer. Every time I try, and whatever I cast it to, it's always null (in win8.1, .net 4.5.1)

Comment: Problem you're facing is that WMI gets its info from SpoolSrv.exe -- and the WMI query reports whatever status Spoolsrv provides. If SpoolSrv is _READY_, Win32_Printer exports this as 'Idle' (PrinterStatus = 3 or PrinterState = 0)